# exporting a higher order component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a following loading component which is an HOC

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const isEmpty = prop =>
  prop === null ||
  prop === undefined ||
  (prop.hasOwnProperty("length") && prop.length === 0) ||
  (prop.constructor === Object && Object.keys(prop).length === 0);

const LoadingHOC = loadingProp => WrappedComponent => {
  return class LoadingHOC extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.startTimer = Date.now();
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!isEmpty(nextProps[loadingProp])) {
        this.endTimer = Date.now();
      }
    }

    render() {
      const myProps = {
        loadingTime: ((this.endTimer - this.startTimer) / 1000).toFixed(2)
      };

      return isEmpty(this.props[loadingProp]) ? (
        <div className="loader" />
      ) : (
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...myProps} />
      );
    }
  };
};

export default LoadingHOC;
```

I'm using this in my `Feed` component to have a loading effect.

Feed component is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FeedItem from "./FeedItem";
import LoadingHOC from "./HOC/LoadingHOC";

class Feed extends Component {
  state = {
    filterText: ""
  };

  render() {
    const { loadingTime } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="feed">
        <FeedItem
          contacts={this.props.contacts}
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
        />
        {/* <p>Loading time {loadingTime} seconds</p> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoadingHOC("contacts", Feed);
```

I'm using the `Feed` component in my `App.js` like `<Feed contacts={this.state.contacts} />` this.

However I get the following error - `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

I understand that this is because the HOC is not being called correctly. But what am I doing wrong in `export default LoadingHOC("contacts", Feed);` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HOC is a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function. So you need to call twice

```
export default LoadingHOC("contacts")(Feed);
```